# How is Maven supported in PhpStorm?

Tags: maven, phpstorm

Intellij supports Maven as a native Java tool pretty well.

Now Maven seems to grow more and more attractive for other languages, too.

So my question is how well does PhpStorm support integration of Maven in PHP projects.

Especially regarding:

1. profile generation
2. profile validation
3. different views on profiles
4. build-execution from IDE
5. profile organization
6. ...

I cannot find much on that via Google ... so is that already the end of the story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Maven support in PhpStorm and it's not planned in the nearest releases.
You can [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WI) to the issue tracker.